# CSS does not apply(after the first page) on trying to print a html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML page has content generated dynamically and forms a length of more than 1 page while trying to print.
The problem occurs from the second page where the css does not apply properly.
Border lines for HTML table rows are not completly seen.

The CSS i have applied for the HTML table is

```
border: 1px solid #DADADB;
background:#F3F3F3;
text-align:center;
font-size:15px;
```

FWIW, The content intended to print is placed in a HTML table element which is placed in a DIV.

Comment: Create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that CSS. You need to post something that exhibits the wrong behavior, otherwise it's very hard to guess what the problem might be. Also, does this happen with every browser?

Comment: I have checked print preview in mozilla ,safari ,opera ,chrome and mac browsers. 
All the above browsers do not show proper borders for the table rows from the second page in the preview and same in the print out.Please check the print priview.
Please find the sample code from http://jsfiddle.net/vasavi/5bQzv/5/

Comment: I suggest to seperate css and html and write css rules for your inline styles. This way it will be much easier to find out the error.

Answer (score 0):

In Print View some styles for some elements (if not given in CSS) becomes default. Because of that - all your form elements (input and textarea) in Print View got white background covering borders of table. Solution - set background of inputs and textareas to none.

```
input, textarea {
    background: none;
}
```

And done ;)